# why my routes.xml is not working in admin or on front end view both

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend, magento2.2.2, router

I donot understand why my routes.xml is not working , see this and tell me if you get something wrong in it . thats the code snippet .

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="admin">
            <route frontName="checkcustomattribute" id="checkcustomattribute">
                <module name="CheckCustom_Attributed"/>
            </route>
        </router>
    </config>
```

module is perfectly installed i have checked it , folder structure for admin route is etc/adminhtml/routes.xml , for front router etc/frontend/routes.xml . and i am on developer mode i am seeing no error everything in code structure seems ok so what is going wrong in it . I have even tried different route id and front name .

Comment: shair all file like phtml contoller

Comment: and layout file with thair names because name of layout file is wrong i think

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you enabled your custom module by run the following command:

1. Setup upgrade:

> php bin/magento s:up

2. Check module is enabled:

> php bin/magento module:status CheckCustom_Attributed

Make sure your admin controller extends the **Magento\Backend\App\Action** class
and the controller class must be under **CheckCustom/Attributed/Controller/Adminhtml** folder

With the frontend controller, if you created a controller class, example:

> CheckCustom/Attributed/Controller/Check/Attribute.php

so the url that you should to enter is **{base_url}/checkcustomattribute/check/attribute**

Hope this will solve your issue